# Multiplying from two array variable in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop, foreach

Let say.. I have data like this

```
wij = [0.5, 0.30, 0.25, 0.15, 0.25]
```

and

[image]

As you see.. each data in **wij** is represent from C1 until C5 from table above

**C1=0.5**, **C2=0.30**, **C3=0.25**, **C4=0.15**, **C5=0.25**

So.. i create the wij into array-variable like this:

```
$wij = array(0.5, 0.30, 0.25, 0.15, 0.25);
```

and A1 until A5 rows into array-variable:

```
$nij = array(
    array(150, 15, 2, 2, 3);
    array(500, 200, 2, 3, 2);
    array(200, 10, 3, 1, 3);
    array(350, 100, 3, 1, 2);
);
```

I want to multiplying each data from **wij** with data from A1 until A5 rows, so it will be look like this:

```
A1 = (0.5*150)+(0.30*15)+(0.25*2)+(0.15*2)+(0.25*3)

A2 = (0.5*500)+(0.30*200)+(0.25*2)+(0.15*3)+(0.25*2)

A3 = (0.5*200)+(0.30*10)+(0.25*3)+(0.15*1)+(0.25*3)

A4 = (0.5*350)+(0.30*100)+(0.25*3)+(0.15*1)+(0.25*2)
```

I don't have any clue how to do it using for-loops or foreach-loops. Because each rows in table is not always have 4 data like from table above, it can always 5 rows or more, so I guess it will be work if using for-loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
$wij = array(0.5, 0.30, 0.25, 0.15, 0.25);
$array1 = array(150, 15, 2, 2, 3);
$array2 = array(500, 200, 2, 3, 2);
$array3 = array(200, 10, 3, 1, 3);
$array4 = array(350, 100, 3, 1, 2);
$arrays = array($array1,$array2,$array3,$array4);
$as = array(0,0,0,0);


for($i = 0;$i<4;$i++)
{
    for($t = 0;$t<5;$t++)
    {
    $as[$i] += ($wij[$t]*$arrays[$i][$t]);
    }
    echo "</br>".$as[$i];   
}

?>
```

I can explain for-loop, if you want.

Comment: interesting style, I would write arrays in array, looks much cleaner than 5 variables insreted in array.

Comment: also use foreach loops, better because array size may differ